Can I submit an abstract to a different conference before withdrawing from another?
I submitted a paper to Neurips, but I'm not very happy with the reviews/scores, so I'm thinking about withdrawing my paper to resubmit elsewhere. There is still an opportunity to raise the scores in the discussion phase, so I'm not 100% certain on withdrawing just yet.
If I did withdraw, I was thinking of resubmitting to AAAI. I noticed that the paper deadline for AAAI is after the end of the discussion for Neurips, so it would be possible to see if my scores are raised first. However, the abstract deadline is before. Would this be ok or could this be considered unethical and against the conference rules? Of course, if I were to decide to not withdraw from Neurips, I would then withdraw my abstract and not submit a full paper to AAAI. However, I'm not sure if an abstract submission counts as a submission to multiple conferences.
This has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find a direct answer, as the deadlines have changed this year and the fast track option has been removed.

To be honest, it's surprising that such dominant conferences have overlapping deadlines (usually they take care not to overlap). Do you think that you have a chance of getting accepted?

If you are already thinking about withdrawing, I am sure you are confident that it might not get through at NeurIPS. I would not attempt to send a rebuttal. Reviewers almost always (!) never increase scores. I have my personal experiences (at least twice) with IJCAI. It is better to withdraw, improve the paper and send off somewhere else.

It should be fine, you just need to make sure to withdraw the paper from NeurIPS before the full paper deadline of AAAI, or delete your abstract submission in AAAI before the full paper deadline, so it does not count as double submission.
Abstract submissions in ML conferences are meant to be temporary, you only commit at the full paper deadline, and that is where we would count it as a double submission if it has not been withdrawn from the other conference.
